# What is the best way to exclude a revision from trunk and then bring it back in later?

Tags: svn, branch

We use svn and have code that is supposed to go out in a few days, but there is one revision that we want to exclude from our build since we won't have time to fully QA it.  What's the best way to exclude that revision from trunk?

Should we create a branch, with that revision in it, revert the changes of that revision in trunk, and then once the code goes out merge the revision from that branch back into trunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just revert the changes from this revision and commit, that would still leave the old revision in but it would not be easily found later on.

What you suggest is IMHO the best way to proceed.

Create a branch or a tag to keep the changes and then revert on trunk.
Later when you're ready to integrate the changes you just have to merge back the branch and recommit.

Comment: True...but do I really need to create this branch if I can revert it now by reverse merging, and then merge this revision later since it's saved in the repository?

Comment: Technically it is not "required" to create a branch, it's only for easy reference later. Besides, it reveals the intention that there is a revision "waiting" to be merged back later on. Helps on not forgetting to do it.

Comment: Good point, and it could be a place to review the revision before merging it back into trunk.

Answer (score 2):

How are you indicating what goes into the build? Is it the whole tree in the repository, or are you using svn:externals or what?

If you're using svn:externals, then you can just apply a revision number to that component.

If you're checking out the whole tree, then you can back out the change until you've made the release. You don't need to save it on a branch, it's still there in the repository.

So

```
svn merge -c -<revision-no>
```

should back out the changes that made that particular revision. (You'll then need to commit).

If the revision affected more than just that component, then you can restrict the merge to just that component.

Then afterwards you do another 'merge' to reapply the change:

```
svn merge -c <revision-no>
```

(Notice the lack of '-' before the revision number).

Comment: These revisions were not in externals.  Good call about not needing to save it in the branch...I can just retrieve that revision later and merge it back in.  Thank you.